# Preventing overlapping horizontal bars in a d3.js timeline

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating a timeline of events using d3.js. Some of the events on a row overlap each other. i.e., the next begins before the previous one ends. e.g.:

[image]

For each bar, if it's going to overlap a previous one, I'd like to move it down:

[image]

How would I do this? [Here's a JSfiddle that generates the first example.](https://jsfiddle.net/philgyford/5zecjc6t/2/)

Here's some relevant parts:

```
var spanX = function(d, i) { return xScale(d['begin']); },
    spanY = function(d) { return 0; },
    spanW = function(d, i) {
      return xScale(d['end']) - xScale(d['begin']);
    },
    spanH = 10; 

var span = chart.selectAll('.chart-span')
                    .data(data) 
                    .enter().append('rect')
                      .classed('chart-span', true)
                      .attr('x', spanX)
                      .attr('y', spanY)
                      .attr('width', spanW)
                      .attr('height', spanH);
```

(There are other issues, such as displaying more timelines under each other on the same chart, and displaying a label describing each timeline on the left... but one problem at a time!)

**UPDATE:** For those following along, here's my finished chart: http://spelunker.moma.org/departments/ (2017-02-08)

Comment: Congrats for the "*but one problem at a time*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is creating an algorithm to check the end of the previous bar and setting the y position of the next bar according to that previous bar ending (and such algorithm will be fundamental to your two next questions, *"...displaying more timelines under each other on the same chart, and displaying a label describing each timeline on the left"*).

But, due to simplicity (and laziness), if your data is not dynamic or your chart not terribly complex, you can set (hardcode) the positions in the data:

```
var data = [
      {'begin': 2001, 'end': 2005, 'pos': 1},
      {'begin': 2006, 'end': 2010, 'pos': 1},
      {'begin': 2008, 'end': 2012, 'pos': 2},
      {'begin': 2011, 'end': 2015, 'pos': 3}
];
```

And then defining your y scale and your `spanY`:

```
yScale.domain(data.map(d=> d.pos))
    .range([0, height]);

spanY = function(d) { return yScale(d.pos); }
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = [
      {'begin': 2001, 'end': 2005, 'pos': 1},
      {'begin': 2006, 'end': 2010, 'pos': 1},
      {'begin': 2008, 'end': 2012, 'pos': 2},
      {'begin': 2011, 'end': 2015, 'pos': 3}
    ];

      var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 40},
          width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 120 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
          xScale = d3.scaleBand(),
     yScale = d3.scaleBand(),
          xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale),
          minX = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d['begin']; }),
          maxX = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d['end']; });

      xScale.domain(d3.range(minX, maxX+1));

      xScale.rangeRound([0, width]);
   
   yScale.domain(data.map(d=> d.pos))
    .range([0, height]);

      var spanX = function(d, i) { return xScale(d['begin']); },
          spanY = function(d) { return yScale(d.pos); },
          spanW = function(d, i) {
            return xScale(d['end']) - xScale(d['begin']);
          },
          spanH = 10; 

      var chart = d3.select('.chart')
            .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr('height', height + margin.left + margin.right)
          .append('g')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   // Add x axis
      chart.append("g")
              .attr("class", "axis axis-x");

      chart.select('.axis-x')
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .call(xAxis);

   // Add spans
      var span = chart.selectAll('.chart-span')
                        .data(data) 
                        .enter().append('rect')
                          .classed('chart-span', true)
                          .attr('x', spanX)
                          .attr('y', spanY)
                          .attr('width', spanW)
                          .attr('height', spanH);
```

```css
.chart-span {
      fill: #333;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg class="chart"></svg>
```

PS: Again, this *hardcoded* solution will not be a good one for your next two questions (*"...displaying more timelines under each other on the same chart, and displaying a label describing each timeline on the left"*). When you post these questions, describe in better details how the data can be, so people can think about a good algorithm to calculate the bars' positions.

Comment: Many thanks for this Gerardo. The idea of giving each row the `pos` value, and using that on the y-axis was exactly the kind of thing I was missing. And simpler than anything I'd have come up with!